# Solving Coupled ODEs

Tags: plot, syntax-error, ode, differential-equations, odeint

I am facing a syntax error while solving the following coupled differential equations using the odeint function. My equations are the following:

![\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{Pe^{e^{3t}}{a^{3}Hv}]

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{-a^{3}ve^{-\frac{1}{M^{2}sigma^{2}}e^{3t}m^{2}MSin(2\frac{\phi}{M})}{2H}$$
where

$$H=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}(\frac{P^{2}+0.5\sigma^{2}}{2a^{6}e^{6t}v^{2}})+(\frac{m^{2}M^{2}}{4})(1-cos(\frac{2\phi}{M})e^{-\frac{1}{sigma^{2}M^{2}}})}$$.

Both $\phi$ and $P$ are the functions of t.

I have tried to plot these variables against time using the following code, and it is giving me a syntax error. I think it is a small mistake that I am going somewhere, but I can't figure that out. Please help.

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import math as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
a=1
m=0.5
M=1
sigma=1
v=1
def system(phi,m,sigma,M,a,v):
   phi1=phi[0]
   P=phi[1]
   H=np.sqrt(((1/3)*(P**2+0.5*sigma**2)
     /(2*(a**6)*np.exp(6*t)*v**2))+((0.25*(m**2)*(M**2))*(1-
   np.cos(2*phi1/M))))
   dphi_dt=P*np.exp(-3*t)/(a**3*v*H)
   dP_dt=-a**3*v*np.exp(-(1/(sigma*M)**2)*m**2*M*np.sin(2*
          (phi1/M))/(2*H)                           
   s=[dP_dt,dphi_dt]                   
   return s #error is being shown here(Syntax)

   
t=linspace(-10,10)
phi_0=[0,0.1]#initial conditions

phi=odeint(system,phi_0,t,args=(a,v,sigma,M,m))
plt.plot(t,phi[:,0])
plt.plot(t,phi[:,1])
plt.show()
```

I am attaching the picture of the equations [image: two coupled odes] as well.

Comment: Is this the indentation of your original code? Then read up on how indentation defines scoping levels in Python, the function `system` has no body.

Comment: This was not the indentation of my original code. I have made the editions here. But the error is on the same line of the code, and I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: The exponential in `dP_dt` is missing a closing parenthesis. The exponent does not correspond to the exponent in the formulas. `linspace` is missing its namespace `np`. `def system` is missing the `t` argument. The extra parameters are not in the same order as the `args` parameter in `odeint`.

Comment: @luitz Thank you so much. It is now working, and my bad, I couldn't see that.

Comment: I tried one more thing, I want to plot derivative(H,t) by importing the derivative from Scipy. When I do, it keeps giving me an error. Can you please help in this regard? It is plotting (t,H) just fine.

Comment: H is a number, the value of the expression. There is no difference quotient of a single number.

Comment: Yes, actually I want to plot derivative of H w.r.t. t. Should I define a function first which has the time derivative expression of H? I plotted the expression as follows(editing the question).